# How do you store/retrieve the output of print() in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to take the output of `print()` in Swift and put it in a UILabel or UITextView for demonstration purposes (going to add some styling, etc). How do you store/retrieve the output of `print()`?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to achieve? If you have print(someTextVar) you can just say label.text = someTextVar. I guess you are looking for something more elaborate?

Comment: Well the print handles lots of objects and other nice things that I want. I'm teaching a class. I want to style the printing to make it more readable. The console is hard sometimes to identify things.

Comment: Why can you not assign those things directly to label.text? label.text = "Our object is \\(object)" will work. Can you come up with at least one scenario when the output of print() will be different from identical assignment to label.text? I am asking you this because I am still struggling to understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

In my view you are overcomplicating something. If your aim is to pass a string literal:

```
print("Your complicated literal with some \(objects)")
```

you can easily assign it to the text property of `UILabel`:

```
label.text = "Your complicated literal with some \(objects)"
```

More generally, everything that can be passed to `print()` can be assigned to `text` property of `UILabel`.

If your aim is to simultaneously output something to console and also assign it to `UILabel` then simply create a helper function:

```
func myCustomPrint(inputString: String) {
    print(inputString)
    myLogLabel.text = inputString
}
```

You can then call:

```
myCustomPrint("Your complicated literal with some \(objects)")
```

And you will get the message printed in console and displayed in a label.

If you are worried that some formatting will be lost (like "Optional(your_variable)") be assured that it will not be. I have previously used regular `UILabel` to log statements for a notification centre widget and the output was identical to `print()`